# Spring Boot: Oauth2: Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I am trying to use spring boot oauth2 to accomplish stateless authentication and authorisation. However, I am struggling to it working.

Here is my code:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
//@EnableEurekaClient
//@EnableZuulProxy
@Configuration
public class AuthServiceApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AuthServiceApp.class, args);
  }
}
```

**Authorisation Config:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class Oauth2ServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
  private AuthenticationManager auth;

  @Autowired
  private DataSource dataSource;

  @Autowired
  private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailService;

  @Autowired
  private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;


  @Bean
  public JdbcTokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
  }

  @Bean
  protected AuthorizationCodeServices authorizationCodeServices() {
    return new JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices(dataSource);
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
    security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    // @OFF
    endpoints
          .authorizationCodeServices(authorizationCodeServices())
          .authenticationManager(auth)
          .userDetailsService(userDetailService)
          .tokenStore(tokenStore());
    // @ON
  }


  @Override
  public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

    // @OFF
    clients.jdbc(dataSource)
           .withClient("client")
           .secret("secret")
           .authorizedGrantTypes("password","refresh_token", "client_credentials")
           .authorities("USER")
           .scopes("read", "write")
           .autoApprove(true)
           .accessTokenValiditySeconds(60)
           .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(300);
    // @ON
  }
}
```

**Resource Server Config:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {


  @Autowired
  private CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint customAuthenticationEntryPoint;

  @Autowired
  private CustomLogoutSuccessHandler customLogoutSuccessHandler;


  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @OFF
          http
              .sessionManagement()
              .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
              .and()
              .exceptionHandling()
              .authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntryPoint)
              .and()
              .logout()
              .logoutUrl("/oauth/logout")
              .logoutSuccessHandler(customLogoutSuccessHandler)
              .and()
              .csrf()
//            .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/oauth/authorize"))
              .disable()
              .headers()
              .frameOptions().disable()
              .and()
              .authorizeRequests()
              .antMatchers("/identity/**").authenticated();
   // @ON
  }
}


@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
  }

  @Override
  @Bean
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @OFF
    http
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin().permitAll();
   // @ON
  }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class AuthController {

  @PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasScope('read')")
  @GetMapping("/user")
  public Principal getUser(Principal user) {
     return user;
  }
}
```

I can get the access token using POSTMAN. I am using the same access token in the header to get the user details as `http://localhost:8082/identity/user` before it gets expired. However, I get login page html response with following log on console:

```
2017-05-24 22:55:16.070 DEBUG 16899 --- [nio-8082-exec-9] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 301C6EDD36372CF9C553FCFCD4AA47E3; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2017-05-24 22:55:16.070 DEBUG 16899 --- [nio-8082-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /user at position 10 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2017-05-24 22:55:16.070 DEBUG 16899 --- [nio-8082-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /user at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2017-05-24 22:55:16.070 DEBUG 16899 --- [nio-8082-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /user at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2017-05-24 22:55:16.070 DEBUG 16899 --- [nio-8082-exec-9] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/login'
2017-05-24 22:55:16.070 DEBUG 16899 --- [nio-8082-exec-9] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /user; Attributes: [authenticated]
2017-05-24 22:55:16.071 DEBUG 16899 --- [nio-8082-exec-9] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 301C6EDD36372CF9C553FCFCD4AA47E3; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2017-05-24 22:55:16.071 DEBUG 16899 --- [nio-8082-exec-9] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@55b4f25d, returned: -1
2017-05-24 22:55:16.071 DEBUG 16899 --- [nio-8082-exec-9] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
```

But it seems like I have been authenticated when making first call to get the access token to `oauth/token`:

```
2017-05-24 22:54:35.966 DEBUG 16899 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /oauth/token; Attributes: [fullyAuthenticated]
2017-05-24 22:54:35.966 DEBUG 16899 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@50c8f5e8: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@af12f3cb: Username: client; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@21a2c: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 2F070B741A55BD1E47933621D9127780; Granted Authorities: USER
2017-05-24 22:54:35.966 DEBUG 16899 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@61f8721f, returned: 1
2017-05-24 22:54:35.966 DEBUG 16899 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorization successful
2017-05-24 22:54:35.966 DEBUG 16899 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2017-05-24 22:54:35.966 DEBUG 16899 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2017-05-24 22:54:35.967 DEBUG 16899 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /oauth/token
2017-05-24 22:54:35.968 DEBUG 16899 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.postAccessToken(java.security.Principal,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException]
2017-05-24 22:54:35.975 DEBUG 16899 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] .o.p.p.ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter : Getting access token for: client
2017-05-24 22:54:35.975 DEBUG 16899 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_1_, user0_.enabled as enabled2_1_, user0_.name as name3_1_, user0_.password as password4_1_, user0_.username as username5_1_ from user user0_ where user0_.username=?
Hibernate: select roles0_.user_id as user_id1_2_0_, roles0_.role_id as role_id2_2_0_, role1_.id as id1_0_1_, role1_.role as role2_0_1_ from user_role roles0_ inner join role role1_ on roles0_.role_id=role1_.id where roles0_.user_id=?
2017-05-24 22:54:36.125  INFO 16899 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] o.s.s.o.p.token.store.JdbcTokenStore     : Failed to find access token for token 180c2528-b712-4088-9cce-71e9cc7ccb94
2017-05-24 22:54:36.232 DEBUG 16899 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
2017-05-24 22:54:36.232 DEBUG 16899 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

May be I am configuring something wrong. What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you doing the HTTP Authentication header correctly? `Authorization: Bearer ${token}`

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar issue and found that the `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter` was not getting invoked by the filter chain and because of which, user was not getting authenticated and hence treated as anonymous.

Am using Spring-boot 1.5.3 version and I added below line in application.yml to fix the ordering.

```
security.oauth2.resource.filter-order=3
```

There must be a log statement present which shows that its getting invoked

```
DEBUG 34386 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /foo at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter'
```

Reference - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/993

Comment: This tip really solved the mess!.. weird things were happening on the filters invocation order.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: After couple of days of nightmare this is the only thing that solved my similar problem! Thank you! @Rites

Comment: shall upgrade to latest one.

Comment: Adding such line in application.yml solves the problem in 
Spring Version 1.5.2.RELEASE too.
Tnx

Answer (score 2):

To use

```
.authorizedGrantTypes("password","refresh_token", "client_credentials")
```

you need to open access to

```
/auth/token
```

in security configuration of your Authorization Server

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    code...
    http
        .antMatcher("/**")
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
    code...     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem and managed to fix it by explicitly disabling some spring autoconfiguration:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = [OAuth2AutoConfiguration::class,
   SecurityAutoConfiguration::class, SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration::class])
```

Answer (score 0):

Also check if you are using multiple OAuth2 filters coming from multiple auth-related dependices/libraries.

In my case I was using

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Along with another custom OAuth2 library used in my organization, which caused the spring library to attempt to authenticate before the custom (correct) one, and with no credentials fed to it of course throwing this exact exception.

My service calls worked once I removed the Spring OAuth2 dependency.